# SQL Server - How to solve FIFO Cost of OHB… function, cursor,?

Tags: sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2, fifo, with-statement

SQL Server 2008 R2 - Need to solve FIFO cost of items on hand. To do this I need to add the cost for the most recent receipts quantity up to the current on hand balance(OHB).

So lets say I have

```
Item : b1234 
OHB : 5
```

Receipts:

```
RctNumb | Item  | QTYRct | RctCostPerItem | DATERECD
rct05   | b1234 |      1 |           1.00 | 20160822
rct04   | b1234 |      3 |           2.00 | 20160820
rct03   | b1234 |      3 |           1.25 | 20160819
rct02   | b1234 |      2 |           2.50 | 20160818
rct01   | b1234 |      8 |           2.00 | 20160810
```

Here I would need: (1*1.00)+(3*2.00)+(1*1.25) = CostofOHB = 8.25

I have no idea how to address this with SQL.

Comment: Why isn't four space prefix preserving my white-space?

Comment: Because you need an **empty line** between a title and the next paragraph to get that effect

Comment: What you need is a running total. With 2012 it's pretty easy and efficient. With 2008R2 you need to do more complex SQL with self non-equijoin that is considerably slower.

Comment: Take a look here: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals . He has done some benchmarking on various methods. The queries presented are for a single running total but it can easily be adapted for multiple running totals. According to this article your best bet is cursors (even though we all try to avoid them like the plauge). Of course if you can switch to 2012 it's a no-brainer

Comment: thank you @P.Kouvarakis I will try to work with that. I have never used cursors before. If I get it to work I will post my solution here. Understanding I will likely have flaws...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this thanks to hints from other sources. 
[running-totals](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals)
[nested-cursors-w-errors](http://truelogic.org/wordpress/2015/01/03/nested-cursors-in-t-sql/)
It is very slow compared to the over(order by) option in 2012 or later.

```
DECLARE @FiFo TABLE
(
RctNumb | Item  | QTYRct | RctCostPerItem | DATERECD
    OHBFIFOCOST     decimal(19,5),
    OHB     decimal(19,5),
    SumRctInvcd decimal(19,5),
    QtyToCost       decimal(19,5),
    ITEM        nvarchar(65) PRIMARY KEY,
    ReportDate  [datetime2](0) 

);
 declare @ITEM as char(31)
 declare @OHB      as decimal(19,5)


 declare @outer_cursor cursor
 declare @inner_cursor cursor

 declare    @RctNumb        nvarchar(32)
 declare    @RCTITEM    as nvarchar(65) 
 declare    @QTYRct     decimal(19,5)
 declare    @SumRctInvcd    decimal(19,5)
 declare    @QtyToCost      decimal(19,5)
 declare    @RctCostPerItem     decimal(19,5)
 declare    @OHBCOST        decimal(19,5)
 declare    @OHBrem         decimal(19,5)
 declare    @rowIndex       int
 declare    @DATERECD       datetime


 declare @fetch_outer_cursor int
 declare @fetch_inner_cursor int

 set @outer_cursor  = cursor static local for 

Select 
    ITEM
    ,OHB
    from ItemMaster
    where OHB > 0 

  /*loop through top level cursor*/
  open @outer_cursor 
  fetch next from @outer_cursor into @ITEM, @OHB 
  select @fetch_outer_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS

  while @fetch_outer_cursor = 0
  begin
     /*loop through second level cursor*/
        set @inner_cursor  = cursor static local for 
        select 
            RctNumb
            ,QTYRct
            ,RctCostPerItem
            ,ITEM
            ,DATERECD
            ,rowIndex
        from RctTbl 
        Where ITEM = @ITEM
        Order By rowIndex desc

     open @inner_cursor
     fetch next from @inner_cursor into @RctNumb, @QTYRct, @RctCostPerItem, @RCTITEM, @DATERECD, @rowIndex

     set @fetch_inner_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS
     while @OHBrem >0  and @fetch_inner_cursor = 0
     begin

        set @OHBrem         = @OHBrem - @QTYRct
        set @QtyToCost      =  case 
                                When @SumRctInvcd + @QTYRct <= @OHB Then @QTYRct
                                else @OHB - @SumRctInvcd
                            end
        set @OHBCOST        = case 
                                When @SumRctInvcd + @QTYRct <= @OHB Then @OHBCOST + (@QtyToCost * @RctCostPerItem)
                                else @OHBCOST + (@QtyToCost * @RctCostPerItem)
                            end
        set @SumRctInvcd    = @SumRctInvcd + @QtyToCost

        fetch next from @inner_cursor into @RctNumb, @QTYRct, @RctCostPerItem, @RCTITEM, @DATERECD, @rowIndex

        set @fetch_inner_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS
     end
     close @inner_cursor
     deallocate @inner_cursor
        INSERT @FiFo(OHBFIFOCOST, OHB,  ITEM, ReportDate, QtyToCost, SumRctInvcd)
        SELECT @OHBCOST, @OHB, @ITEM, GETDATE(), @QtyToCost, @SumRctInvcd;

     fetch next from @outer_cursor into  @ITEM, @OHB  
     set @fetch_outer_cursor = @@FETCH_STATUS


  end

  close @outer_cursor  
  deallocate @outer_cursor 
  select * from @FiFo
```